# Building ansible inventory with 1 IP multiple host name

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Can i know, is this possible to have 1 IP with multiplle inventory host name as below

```
[server_name_1]
[server_name_2]
192.168.172.22
```

Comment: please explain how you want it to work.  do you want the task to be run on each named host even though the IP is the same?

Comment: your syntax is confusing groups with hosts; do you mean you want that .22 host to be in multiple groups, or you mean multiple hostnames for that same IP like Daniel asked?

Comment: I will have 2 different playbook. ! playbook will use server_name_1 whereas another plabook will be using server_name_2. There is a reason as the  server_name is fixe the 1 and 2 will be passed from jenkins

Comment: @VladimirBotka, can i know why remove the bracket? As i check in ansible inventory there should be bracket

Answer (score 0):

The host file entry that you have mentioned over here, When you will run it there will be no errors but:-
The Following entry when you will use the hostname in your playbook like this

```
---
- hosts: server_name_1
```

```
PLAY [server_name_1] 
***************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

It will produce no-host match as there is no IP associated with that Block. If you use the second one with proper key and access will work fine. But the above host file is syntactically correct.